# Prolog: Difference of two lists

Tags: list, prolog

Pretty new to Prolog. I'm trying to give two lists and have the difference of the two returned to me. The second list can have bound variables and unbound variables in it. I've tried tracing this and it recurses all the way through and gives me a correct list in NewL, but then on the way back it negates all the deletes I've made. What is going wrong ? Thanks for the help!

```
% Find difference between two lists, return result in Difference
difference(List,[H|T],Difference) :-   % When H is unbound var, use Tail
    var(H),!,difference(List,T,Difference),!.

difference(List,[H|T],Difference) :- % When H is bound var, remove from List.
    subtract(List,[H],NewL),
    difference(NewL,T,Difference),!.
```

Comment: inserting random cuts in a predicate is usually a bad way to go about solving bugs : ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that subtract/3 comes from [SWI-Prolog library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3), and thus is correct, you are left with just one possibility: you forgot to declare the base case on the second argument, that drives the recursion.

And take in account the comment from @mog, cuts should be used **just** when required. Of course, to decide when **are** required can be difficult...

Comment: difference(List,[],Difference) :-
     Difference is List.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. When tracing I get this. 
Last steps when trying: difference([1,2,3,4],[3,4],Dif).
...

Call: (9) _G541 is [1, 2] ? creep
ERROR: '.'/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2]' ("x" must hold one character)
   Exception: (9) _G541 is [1, 2] ? 

Idk what I'm missing. I want prolog to match the Dif to the result I compute, but instead the recursion backtracks and my computed result is lost.

Comment: just a syntax error: *is* evaluates *arithmetic*, just use *=* to unify a var

Comment: That solved it, thanks. Stupid mistake. I actually tried it before but abandoned it because it didn't work. Thanks chac and mog!